# how to keep hosts config after docker restart

Tags: docker

I am edit `/etc/hosts` in docker container,but the hosts config is lost when I restart nginx docker container.Is it possible to keep the hosts config do not lost when restart container? I am read internet suggest to add parameter when docker run,but my container already exists.

Comment: To make changes permanent, stop that container and run a new one with `--add-host` parameter.

Comment: As a general rule you should avoid changing `/etc/hosts` at all; it’s difficult to keep in sync at scale.  In a pure-Docker context you can use Docker’s internal DNS system to give you hostnames for other containers.  In a larger context you can run a dedicated name server (BIND, dnsmasq) or a service-discovery system that provides DNS (Kubernetes, Consul).